# Combine .change for 2 different selectors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have this script which calculates the result (`totale`) of an operation involving 3 variables: `coefficiente`, which depends on `anno`, and `importo`.

```
$("#anno").change(function () {
    var anno = $("option:selected", this);
    var importo = document.getElementById('importo').value;
    coefficiente = anno.attr("coefficiente");
    var totale = ((importo * coefficiente) / 1936.27).toFixed(0);
    $("#risultato").html("circa " + totale + " EUR");
});
```

`anno` is selected by the user through a dropdown list, `coefficiente` is a parameter of the dropdown list linked to the `option` value and `importo` is typed in an `input type="number"`.

I think having a look at [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/roc6dj67/5/) I created will clear everything. :)

What I'd like to have is have the result printed `$("#risultato").html(...)` also when I change the number typed in `input type="number"`, not only selecting an `option` in the dropdown list.

I tried with `$("#anno, #importo")` but the result is only printed if I change both values.. although a `NaN` is shown!

Comment: Nevermind I didn't read your question fully.

Comment: Now try changing that 50 to something else, it will output NaN.
EDIT: Oh ok :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/roc6dj67/7/

Technically, you'd want to add your `coefficiente` as `data-coefficiente` and find it like this, since `coefficiente` is not a valid HTML attribute:

```
var anno = $("#anno");
var importo = $('#importo');
anno.on('change', changeFunc);
importo.on('keyup', changeFunc);

function changeFunc(event) {
    var coefficiente = anno.find('option:selected').data("coefficiente"); // use .data() not .attr()
    var totale = ((importo.val() * coefficiente) / 1936.27).toFixed(0);
    $("#risultato").html("circa " + totale + " EUR");
}
```

Comment: Also, some browsers are weird at times using numbers with `.val()` and `.data()` or `.attr()` - you therefore might want to `parseFloat()` those values before using them in a calculation.

Comment: would it work if I do it directly for the total? $("#risultato").html("circa " + parseFloat(totale) + " EUR");

Comment: No, you would do it on the individual values first.